# Pause Console in C++ program

Tags: c++

Which is best way to pause the console in C++ programs?

1. using `cin.get()`
2. or using `system("pause")`
3. or using C functions like `getch()` or `getchar()`?

Is it true that use of `system("pause")` leads to non portable code and can't work in UNIX?

Is cin.get() is better to use to pause console?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There might be a best way (like using the portable `cin.get()`), *but a **good** way doesn't exist*. A program that has done its job should quit and give its resources back to the computer.

And yes, any usage of `system()` leads to unportable code, as the parameter is passed to the shell that owns your process.

Having pausing-code in your source code sooner or later causes hassles:

- someone forgets to delete the pausing code before checking in

  - now all working mates have to wonder why the app does not close anymore
  - version history is tainted
- `#define` is hell
- it's annoying to anyone who runs your code from the console
- it's very, very, very annoying when trying to start and end your program from within a script; quadly annoying if your program is part of a pipeline in the shell, because if the program does not end, the shell script or pipeline won't, too

Instead, explore your IDE. It probably has an option not to close the console window after running. If not, it's a great justification to you as a developer worth her/his money to always have a console window open nearby.

Alternatively, you can make this a program option, but I personally have never seen a program with an option `--keep-alive-when-dead`.

**Moral of the story:** This is the user's problem, and not the program's problem. Don't taint your code.

Comment: +1. That request comes from the need to read the output in the console if run by an IDE, which will close the console as soon as the appplication terminates. An application run through a "real" command prompt will not suffer of this problem.

Comment: @black: If the IDE lacks the feature to keep open the console, then that's a great justification to always keep a console open nearby. Pausing the program yields to problems in version control, because sooner or later someone forgets to delete the pausing-code again, or to problems with #define-macros, or whatever. I think I should expand my answer a bit :)

Comment: @phresnel: you says that " it's very, very, very annoying when trying to start and end your program from within a script; quadly annoying if your program is part of a pipeline in the shell. "  How & why it is annoying?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: Because when the program does not end, the shell script or pipeline invoking the program will not end, too.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Why is it?

Comment: @SebastianMach Actually, "that" is correct here, and "which" is not. Technically.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to write portable C++ code, then I'd suggest using `cin.get()`.

`system("PAUSE")` works on Windows, since it requires the execution of a console command named "`PAUSE`". But I'm not sure that other operating systems like Linux or other Unix derivatives support that. So that tends to be non-portable.

Since C++ already offers `cin.get()`, I see no compelling reason to use C `getch()`.

Comment: C `getch()` wouldn't be recommended anyway, since it's not defined in ISO C++ or POSIX (it's from MS `conio.h`).

Comment: conio.h stands for CONsole Input/Output, was used primarily in MS-DOS, left for compatibility reasons and obviously not standard.

Answer (score 6):

The *best way* depends a lot on the platform(s) being targeted, debug vs. release usage etc.

I don't think there is one *best* way, but to "force" a wait on enter type scenario in a fairly generic way, especially when debugging (typically this is either compiled in or out based on `NDEBUG` or `_DEBUG`), you could try `std::getline` as follows

```
inline void wait_on_enter()
{
    std::string dummy;
    std::cout << "Enter to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, dummy);
}
```

With our without the "enter to continue", as needed.

Comment: @phresnel programs serve user needs.  So any user need is also a programm need.  Do you really need to spam all the answers to this valid question with your personal opinion ?

Comment: @phresnel; True, general legitimate use of such constructs are limited.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is best way to pause the console in C++ programs?

`system("pause");` and `getch();` (which comes from the DOS world, IIRC) are both unportable.

> Is cin.get() is better to use to pause console?

As the only one *portable* and *standard* option, I would say it is, but I personally believe one should not write interactive console programs, i.e. programs which actually pause the console or prompt for input (unless there is a *really* good reason for that, because that makes shell scripting much harder). Console programs should interact with the user via command line arguments (or at least that kind of interaction should be the default one).

Just in case you need pausing the program for the my-program-is-launched-from-the-IDE-and-immediately-closed-but-I-don't-have-enough-time-to-see-the-result reason — don't do that. Just configure your IDE or launch *console* programs right from the console.

Comment: Interactive console programs are rather common in the Unix- and Linux-worlds. The difference to this question's code is that they _do_ quit after the work is done.

Answer (score 2):

`system("pause")` is a perfectly valid way of pausing a console in Windows, "pause" is actually a system command that windows recognizes and as such, you never have to worry about it calling a program by the same name, or anything like that.  The idea of `system("pause")` being dangerous in that regard is myth.

**However** this is not the case *outside* of windows, so it is best to use the preprocessor to delineate between the platforms.

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
if(argc <= 1) // optional, prevents pausing if the user runs "program.exe -lol"
    system("pause");
#endif
```

You can add preprocessor branches for pausing in other platforms, as you see fit... But in my opinion, giving it to Windows is more than enough, as Linux users are more likely to run things from a console anyway.  Additionally, if you have a command line parser, you can shutdown the pause with certain arguments.  (The condition in the code snippet you see, is literally "any argument at all" as just a lazy example.)

Comment: Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *good* way to do that, but you should use portable solution, so avoid `system()` calls, in your case you could use `cin.get()` or `getch()` as you mentioned in your question, also there is one advice. Make **all** pauses controlled by one (or very few) preprocessor definitions.

For example:

*Somewhere in global file:*

```
#define USE_PAUSES
#ifndef _DEBUG    //I asume you have _DEBUG definition for debug and don't have it for release build
#undef USE_PAUSES
#endif
```

*Somewhere in code*

```
#ifdef USE_PAUSES
cin.get();
#endif
```

This is not universal advice, but you should protect yourself from putting *pauses* in release builds and these should have easy control, my mentioned *global file* may not be so global, because changes in that may cause really long compilation.

Answer (score 1):

*(My answer is partially based on that from [Yoank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089342/3258851), and partially on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470658/cin-get-does-not-wait-for-a-keypress-even-with-cin-ignore-before-it#comment58637853_35470996) by [Justin Time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5386374/justin-time) on another question.)*

```
cout << endl << "Press <Enter> to continue...";
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that there is a way to get what you want, but it will require to use some a third party library (or that you write the platform dependent code yourself).

As far as I'm concerned, the biggest drawback with cin is that you are required to hit Return, and not just any key.

Assuming you had a key-listener you could quite easily write a function that waits for the user to hit *any* key. However finding a platform independent key listener is no trivial task, and will most likely require you to load parts of a larger library.

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
char wait_for_key() {
    int key;
    while ( ! (key == key_pressed(ANY)) ) {
          this_thread::yield();
    }
    return convert_virtual_key_to_char(key);
}
```

The actual function would obviously be quite different from what I wrote, depending on the library you use.

I know the following libraries have keylisteners (Feel free to add more in an edit if you know of any.):

- [keycode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737566/rolling-ones-own-keyboard-input-system-in-c-c)
- [SDL](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState)

Comment: All this hassle and code-tainting for something that is not the program's problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

I always used a couple lines of code which clear the input stream of any characters and then wait for input to ignore.

Something like:

```
void pause() {
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl << "Press any key to continue...";
    cin.ignore();
}
```

And then any time I need it in the program I have my own pause(); function, without the overhead of a system pause. This is only really an issue when writing console programs that you want to stay open or stay fixated on a certain point though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
void pause()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::string dummy;
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue . . .";
    std::getline(std::cin, dummy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but I think it will help others.

Part of imitating system("pause") is imitating what it asks the user to do: "Press any key to continue . . . " So, we need something that does not wait for simply a return as std::cin.get() would do. Even getch() has its problems when used twice (the second time call has been noticed to skip pausing generally if it's immediately paused again afterwards on the same key press). I think it has to do with the input buffer. System("pause") is usually not recommended, but we still need something to imitate what users might already expect. I prefer getch() because it doesn't echo to the screen, and it works dynamically.

The solution is to do the following using a do-while loop:

```
void Console::pause()
{ 
    int ch = 0;

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue . . . ";

    do {
        ch = getch();
    } while (ch != 0);

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now it waits for the user to press any key. If it's used twice, it waits for the user again instead of skipping.