# Is there a universal sleep and a universal pause command in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos

I'm looking for a universal sleep command and also a universal pause command for C++. It needs to work for Windows, MAC, and Linux computers. If anyone knows of any great portability command, please let me know.

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::milli(1000))`

Comment: By pause, do you mean pause at the console?

Comment: On the console pause, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24776262/3747990

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ 11 has

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
```

and C++14 has

```
using namespace std::literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
```

as @Creris mentioned Boost has you covered for C++03 on Win32 and platforms that have pthreads

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
```

Comment: just to add, if your compiler doesnt support C++11, you are out of luck for standard solution, but I believe boost has `boost::thread` that works on C++03 on multiple platforms