# "cin" do not work when I use it in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

when I try to compile a simple program like this: 
// i/o example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "The value you entered is " << i;
    cout << " and its double is " << i * 2 << ".\n";
    return 0;

}
```

it starts, but when I put the integer value and press ENTER, it closes. I really don't know why it happens since it works good when I use Dev C++. And if I want to just compile my program I need to press ctrl+f5? Thank you.

Comment: Run the program from a `cmd` window, or set a breakpoint at the `return 0;` statement and run it in debug mode.

Comment: And if you remove the input and just output something, I bet you'll still have the same problem. `cin` is very likely not relevant.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ is right, but he gave you the solution without explaining what happens. The "problem" is that your program reaches the end very quickly, so quickly that you can't even see the output, and then the window is closed immediately, because the program is over. So, your program is fine, there are no bugs; you just have to change the way you run it. If you run the program from `cmd`, the window doesn't close at the end; if you set a breakpoint, it does but it "pauses" before it, so that you can have a look at the result.

Comment: Add a `int foo; cin >> foo` at the end right before return 0. Also, if you're not already, use the Roswell Dev C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is likely happening is that the computer returns the two `cout` lines and then runs `return 0`, shutting down the program.

Since there is no `pause`, it just executes the code and exits, without waiting for further user input. This is what is giving the appearance of the program not working well.

If you put a breakpoint, or run the code in debug mode, or add a [pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program), your code will show the output as well.

And for future reference, you'll want to keep your questions to just one question per question. The `Ctrl + F5` question can be found via Google or by searching SO.