# Checking input on a char variable

Tags: c++, validation, char

I'm trying to validate input for a quit/return question in my program so the user is forced to enter either `'r'` or `'q'`.

I have managed to get it almost working. The problem is if the user enters `'r'` or `'q'` at the beginning followed by random letters then the program accepts that input. Any ideas on how to get the program to allow only a single `'r'` or `'q'` ?

```
void exit()
{
    char choice;
    bool badInput;

    do
    {
        cout << "Press 'r' to return to the menu\nPress 'q' to quit the program\n\n" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        badInput = cin.fail();
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (badInput == true && choice == 'r' && choice == 'q' && (cin.peek() == EOF));


        if (choice == 'q')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Bye!\n";
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if (choice == 'r')
        {
            system("CLS");
            main();
        }
        else
        {
            exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read an entire line of input. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Testing vs. `true` is usually pointless, that's what a logical condition inside an `if` already does. `while (badInput && ...` should suffice.

Comment: Instead of explicitly requiring that they only input `r` or `q`, it might be easier to take the first letter of what they input, then ignore everything after it.  Also, a `do ... while (choice == 'r')` loop would likely suit your purpose better than calling `main()` again or defining a function named `exit()` in the global namespace.  \[Note that the C++ standard says [you're not allowed to call `main()` from inside the program itself](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3), unlike some other languages.\]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a very strange way of approaching this problem that's got a lot of issues. In particular, creating a function called `exit()` is problematic since that's a core function, and calling it recursively to try and get input is likewise not a good plan. You already have a loop, you just need to use it more effectively.

Likewise, `main()` is called automatically and you should never have reason to call it manually.

Here's a first pass rewrite:

```
void getInput()
{
    char choice;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Press 'r' to return to the menu\nPress 'q' to quit the program\n\n" << endl;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'q':
                system("CLS");
                cout << "Bye!\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 'r':
                system("CLS");
                doMain();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously needs more work, but at least should *theoretically* function. In your original code you're demanding that the input value be simultaneously two different things which is an impossibility, that code will never work.

I'd also encourage you to stop doing things like `system("CLS")` and `system("PAUSE")` and instead do something in C++ natively. That's not portable code and it's terribly clunky as it depends on commands from 1980s DOS.

Comment: This is indeed rewritten in a way that makes more sense, however it does the exact same thing as my code. What I mean by that is that it accepts a string as long as 'r' or 'q' is the first thing inputted which isn't what I need.

I have a exit procedure because i'm creating a calculator program for my assignment, what I wanted is to call exit(); at the end of every other function instead of creating this code in every function, makes sense right?

May I ask what you mean by "something in C++ natively"?, I've only started programming in September, so sorry about that

Comment: `exit()` is a standard C function that C++ also depends on, so avoid conflicting with it. `main()` is even more special. If you re-write `exit()` it's like removing the door in the room, you'll have to jump out the window, so don't do it. Calling `system(...)` executes a command external to C++. Doing something C++ natively means using the Standard Library to get the same effect. Generally writing [code like that is an anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program) that's best avoided.

Comment: You may have some further work to do here, I can't complete your assignment for you, but this should be a basis to work from that's at least plausible

Comment: To be fair, the Win NT command prompt accepts `cls` and `pause` in every version of Windows NT, to my knowledge, so it's not exactly limited to 1980s DOS.  So, the code isn't portable, but it should run on any version of Windows.

Comment: @JustinTime What I mean is those commands date from the 1980s and *only* work in DOS or DOS-derived environments.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling the input**

Most implementation use a buffered `cin`, so that input will only be returned once the user press enter. If this is not acceptable to you, you'll have to use OS-dependent functions.

If it's ok for you, then if you read a char, only the first one will be handed over:  the remaining chars until the enter will wait for subsequent reads.  Therefore, instead of reading a single char, I propose you to read a full line into a string:

```
void want_exit() 
{
    const string message="Press 'r' to return to the menu\nPress 'q' to quit the program\n";
    string line; 

    cout << message << endl;
    while (getline(cin, line) && line.length()!=1 
          && tolower(line[0])!='y' && tolower(line[0])!='n') 
    {
        cout << "Invalid input" <<endl << message <<endl; 
        line.resize(0); 
    }
```

Now line contains either a single valid char, or it is empty (in case of premature eof,  meaning, that there was an input redirection and that there will anyway be no more input).

**Processing the input**

You can't call recursively `main()`: you should instead return from the function, and organize the calling function so to continue the process

```
    if (line.empty() ||  tolower(line[0])!='y' ) {
         system("CLS");   // This is non portable 
         cout << "Bye!\nPress enter...";
         cin.getch();    //  as good as system("PAUSE");
         std::exit(0);   // be aware of the naming issue ! 
    } 
    return; 
}
```

The calling function (`main()` ?) would then use it in a loop:

```
while (...) {
    ...
    if (...) 
        want_exit();    
}
```