# C++ Draw a rectangle in different lines

Tags: c++

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in c++ by using 2 for-loops. Everything is fine except the rectangle isn't drawn correctly. Can somebody give me a tip? thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Variabili 
    int base1, altezza1;

    cout << "Inserisci base del rettangolo:";
    cin >> base1;
    cout << "Inserisci l'altezza del rettangolo:";
    cin >> altezza1;

    cout << "I dati che hai inserito sono -> " << "Base:" << base1 << " e Altezza:" << altezza1 << endl;

    // Controllo base e altezza maggiori di zero + scrivo in output il rettangolo con i dati in input
    if(base1 > 0 && altezza1 > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < base1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < altezza1; j++)
            {
                cout << "#";
            }
        }
    }else{
        cout << "Errore";
    }
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is this[image: :]

It should be in rows and columns.

Comment: The error message tells you that "something" is wrong with `system("PAUSE")`. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program Actually, `system("PAUSE")` tries to call the command `PAUSE` that is Windows-specific.

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` is non portable, works only on windows. Looks like you're on non-windows platform

Comment: i know that system pause doesn't work on linux ditros. My answer was another but thanks for the reply i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Print a new line where appropriate using the new line character `\n`. In your case that would be after the inner `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < base1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < altezza1; j++) {
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    std::cout << '\n'; // <--- here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a newline after each row printed as the answer mentioned by ron.  And no need to use `system("PAUSE")`as I think.

```
for(int j=0;j<altezza1;j++)
{
   cout<<"#";
}
cout<<endl; //newline after each row.
```

And try to use readable code for all while posting here in SO.

Comment: `std::endl` flushes the stream, never use it by default.

Answer (score 0):

you need to output newlines characters ('\n', see [the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more informations) and if the rectangle needs to be empty like:

```
####
#  #
####
```

You will need to output spaces too (also [the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Answer (score 0):

You are never printing a newline character. This will cause all of your output to appear on the same line in the terminal.

You can solve your issue by streaming `'\n'` to `std::cout` every time you finish printing a row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < base1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < altezza1; j++) 
    {
        std::cout << "#";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```