# Windows console closing immediately after running a c++ code

Tags: c++, windows, console, visual-studio-2017

I just started using Visual Studio to write C++ code on Windows 10 and I am using the console application template.  My problem is that the console disappears immediately after showing the output of my program even when I simply run a "hello world" example. I tried all kinds of tricks to implement delay but no success.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program/24776299

Comment: are you making the app to wait for any user input before it closes??

Answer (score 2):

I usually put a std::cin line just before main returns. This will cause it to wait for input before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following( assuming that you are not waiting for user input, in that case you can just follow Rich's answer ) :

1. Run it in debugging with a breakpoint on the last line before the main returns.
2. Use a system("pause") at the end before the main returns.( suggesting this just because it's just a hello world program in Visual Studio )

Answer (score 0):

A great way to pause the console in Visual Studios for your purposes is to use `system("pause");` Though its not portable to other OS and some anti-virus systems don't like it. For your purposes it should work well and is easy to see what the line does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong. Better to not encourage bad practices from the start.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah we are using Visual Studios in the tag. `system("pause");` is a perfectly valid way to do it.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I added a disclaimer

Comment: `system` on Windows is unreliable in general because MSVC doesn't use CMD's `/d` option to skip AutoRun commands. Problems related to AutoRun commands can take a long time to solve, since these commands are often set by other programs without consent or advisement. If you're running a simple command, invest the extra effort to call it via `_wspawnl` instead. If you want the console to remain open, simply spawn a shell using the `/d` option. There's no need to run a command in the shell and wait.