# Pause console with modern solution and portable in C++

Tags: c++, console, pause

I read this link [Pause Console in C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program) and I don't still get the correct answer based on my needs.

- I want a function that behaves exactly the same with `system("pause")` but it should be portable and has no additional prints.
- I also don't want `std::cin.get()` and `getchar()` because it still echoes the characters except for the enter key.
- `getch()` still works but it is not portable.

Goal:

- Will proceed after pressing **any** key, not only the enter key. (remember: only 1 key)
- Will not use any libraries aside from the standard library.

Comment: To summarize: It's not possible to fulfill all your requirements. If you don't want any echo you can't do it using standard C++, and need to use non-portable platform-specific code or a third-part library.

Comment: I used to do with `kbhit` but that's not standard nor portable. `#include <conio.h> std::cout<<"(Press a key)"; while(kbhit()==0);`

Comment: What about `std::cout << "Please, press [ENTER] to continue..."; { std::string buffer; std::getline(std::cin, buffer); }`? That's fully C++ standard compliant. All you need is `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>`. You even may consider to wrap it into a function `pause()` if you like.

Comment: You know that there is a stone-age old joke about users who cannot find the "any" key on their keyboard? ;-) (The more sophisticated users, of course, complain about that "any" key didn't exclude Shift, Ctrl, Alt, etc. but they didn't work...)